# Is it possible to get Music+Videos to remember its place even when it falls off the recent apps list?

Tags: 8.0, mediaplayer

On Windows Phone 7.x, the Music+Videos app would remember the position within the album/track/etc. that you were playing, even if the app fell off the "recently used apps" (i.e. back button) list.

With Windows Phone 8 (on a Lumia 1020, running Lumia Black) this no longer appears to be the case - is there a setting that can be changed to keep this position, or do I just have to fiddle with my phone less, and keep it in the recent apps list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a "feature" of the updated version of the built in media player to not retain position; it does seem that going in to the Instagram app does increase the likelihood of this happening, but that may just be a coincidence.